# Is IHttpClientFactory registered in Asp .Net Core 3 by default?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, httpclient, middleware, httpclientfactory

I'm working on Asp.Net Core 3.1 project and it seems that it's possible to resolve an instance of `IHttpClientFactory` via DI without adding **Microsoft.Extensions.Http** package to my project and without registering the middleware (via `AddHttpClient()` method).

```cs
public ServiceClientProxy(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory; // it just works
}
```

In the previous versions of Asp.Net Core the additional setup was required (installing nuget, registering the middleware).

- Does it mean that this service is registered in DI by default automatically under the hood in version 3.1?
- Does it make sense to call `AddHttpClient()` explicitly in the project's middleware?

Comment: Yes, add it. You may be relying on another package that is registering it -- and if you remove that package in the future, it will break. But you can't be 100% sure either way. It doesn't make sense to *not* register it if you actually plan to use it.

Comment: @Andy thank you for answer! I saw that `Asp.Net Core` references **Microsoft.Extensions.Http** package by itself and was confused when I've managed to resolve `IHttpClientFactory` instance without explicitly calling `AddHttpClient()` in `Startup.cs`.
But when I create an empty `Asp.Net Core` 3.1 project `IHttpClientFactory` instance cannot be resolved without explicit registration in startup file.

Comment: @SvjMan Just a side-note: `Startup` class's can have a `Configure` method which does receive an `IHttpClientFactory`:  `void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)` [Sample app](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/HeaderPropagation/samples/HeaderPropagationSample/Startup.cs)

Answer (score 2):

The ability to resolve `IHttpClientFactory` via DI without adding **Microsoft.Extensions.Http** package to my project can be caused by the fact that other third party services used in my project call `AddHttpClient()` in their code.

In case an empty `Asp.Net Core` 3.1 project is created, `IHttpClientFactory` instance cannot be resolved via DI without proper registration in `Startup.cs`

So it makes sense to explicitly call `AddHttpClient()` method in `Startup.cs`